# Get from Pandas dataframe column to features for scikit-learn model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


vectors = pd.Series([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [0.5, 1.5, 2.5], [0.1, 1.1, 2.1]], name='vector')
output = pd.Series([True, False, True], name='target')

data = pd.concat((vectors, output), axis=1)
```

`data` looks like this: a Series of lists of floats, and a Series of booleans:

```
            vector  target
0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]    True
1  [0.5, 1.5, 2.5]   False
2  [0.1, 1.1, 2.1]    True
```

Now, I want to fit a simple scikit-learn LogisticRegression model on top of the vectors to predict the target output.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X=data['vector'], y=data['target'])
```

This does not work, with the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I tried casting my vector data to an np array first, with

```
data['vector'].apply(np.array)
```

But this yields the same error as before.

I can get it to work by executing the following:

```
input_vectors = np.array(data['vector'].to_list())
clf.fit(X=input_vectors, y=data['target'])
```

But this seems quite clunky and bulky - I turn the entire pandas array into a list, then turn it into a numpy array.

I'm wondering if there is a better method here for converting this data format into one that is acceptable to scikit-learn. In reality, my datasets are much larger and this transformation is expensive. Given how compatible scikit-learn and pandas normally are, I imagine I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array to `clf.fit`, not a list / Series of arrays.

Use [`numpy.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression()

clf.fit(X=np.vstack(data['vector']), y=data['target'])

clf.coef_
# array([[0.02622973, 0.02623115, 0.02623258]])

clf.intercept_
# array([0.57262013]))
```

Comment: I timed this 10,000 times compared to my solution and this is about 3x slower, so I don't think it's a better solution.

Comment: The ideal would be not to use a Series of arrays in the first place. Pandas is not designed for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the number of columns, how about:

```
 X = data["vector"].explode().values.astype(float).reshape(-1, 3)
```

This will explose the lists into a single series, get the numpy values, convert them to the proper type (you could use `np.float32` as well since the values don't seem too large) and then reshape with the proper number of columns.